# "Used to" and "be used to" in Italian

Tags: grammar, translation

How could I translate *"used to"* and *"be used to"* in Italian to make my Italian friends understand the difference in meaning?
For example, how would you express the difference between

> I used to drink a lot of coffees when I was young.

and

> I am used to drinking coffee every morning.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully get the difference (apart from the obvious fact that “I used to” is a past tense while “I am used to” is a present tense). Could you rephrase your examples for those of us for whom English is not the mother tongue? Perhaps with both reformulation in a present tense (or both in a past tense)?

Comment: @DaG In English the first sentence is said by somebody who drank a lot of coffee while young but no longer does. The second is said by somebody who is accustomed to drinking coffee -- whether they still do it or not, it's something that would feel normal to them.

Comment: "Used to" -> "Sono abituato a"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Gio says in his answer the locution *to be used to* can be translated as *essere solito*, or (in my opinion more commonly) using the adverbial locution *di solito* followed by the verb at the *presente indicativo*. So I'd translate *I am used to drink coffee every morning* as

> Di solito bevo caffè ogni mattina.

I would express the verb *I used to* with the same construction at the past. So *I used to drink coffee every morning* would be translated as

> Di solito bevevo caffè ogni mattina

Or, if describing a habit, with *avere l'abitudine di*, for example

> Avevo l'abitudine di bere caffè ogni mattina.

Comment: Can we translate "I used to" in italian as "ero solito" and "be used to doing sth" as "essere abituato a fare qualcosa"? If yes, can Italians understand the difference in meaning?

Comment: @Vic Could you be more precise in which difference of meaning you want to capture? I am not sure I am getting it. *Essere abituato a fare qlc* means more or less literally *Having the habit of doing sth* and *essere solito di fare qlc* means *Doing normally sth*. However *essere solito* is not a very common turn of phrase.

Comment: Yes, I know it isn't very common in Italian but I imagine that it can help an Italian understand the meaning. "I am used to doing sth/sth stresses the fact that this is something normal, for example, I'm used to drinking black coffee. "I used to" stresses that the action was a habit or a fact in the past.

Comment: Denis, if the difference between “to use to” and “to be used to” as explained by Emmabee in a comment to the question is correct, perhaps this answer should be adjusted a bit.

Comment: I used to = ero solito... Ero abituato. I am used = sono solito... Sono abituato.

Answer (score 3):

***[Essere solito (di)](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/solito.php) :*** is an expression that conveys the meaning  of "being used to something":

> Sono solito (abituato a ) bere caffè ogni mattina.

Nella loc. Essere solito, solere (seguito da un verbo all'infinito presente, preceduto o no dalla prep. di):

> - è solito alzarsi presto la mattina; sono solito leggere il giornale dopo pranzo; erano soliti di fare una partita a carte

(Hoeply)

Comment: This is a good answer, but you should also address how to translate the difference between *to use to* and *to be used to*.

Answer (score 1):

I used to drink a lot of coffees when I was young.
Bevevo molti caffè quando ero giovane.

I am used to drinking coffee every morning.
Sono abituato a bere il caffè ogni mattina.